# C++ vector change in text.txt file and add text

Tags: c++, file, txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

std::string FilesOpen(std::string command)
{
    const int size_buffer = 2;
    char buffer[size_buffer];
    memset(buffer, 0, size_buffer * sizeof(char));
    std::string result = "";

    // Open pipe to file
    FILE* pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe)
    {
        return "popen failed!";
    }

    // read till end of process:
    while (!feof(pipe))
    {
        // use buffer to read and add to result
        if (fgets(buffer, 2, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            result += buffer;
            memset(buffer, 0, size_buffer * sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main(int* agrc, char* agrv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> pole;
    std::string text;

    // get files names and use to ifstream files
    FilesOpen("ls /root/workspace/src/server > /root/workspace/filestext.txt");

    // get files info size and names 
    FilesOpen("ls -l /root/workspace/src/server > /root/workspace/filelist.txt");

    // get files name and add vector
    std::ifstream files;
    files.open("/root/workspace/filestext.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    if (!files)
    {
        std::cout << "Error not open files" << std::endl;
    }

    while (files >> text)
    {
        pole.push_back(text);
    }

    files.close();

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = pole.begin(); it != pole.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    // replace text in shell
    std::string filereplace = "/root/workspace/testovaci.sh";
    std::ofstream r_file(filereplace.c_str());
    char patch[] = "patch=";

    if (r_file.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; patch[i] != '\0'; i++)
            r_file.put(patch[i]);

        r_file.put('D');
    }

    r_file.close()
}
```

I need to get the contents of the file name from the `filetext.txt` file and **ignore the folders** and list them in the `testovaci.sh` script, which looks like this:

> neco1
> neco2
> neco3
> **patch =**
> neco4
> neco5

I need to put in the `testovaci.sh` file has been added to **patch = "file". "file". "file"**
and the folders were ignored, leaving only **binary files**.

**Please help me**, as I tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to the OS command processor to query the filesystem and save the results to a temporary file? Why are you doing that TWICE when you are not even using one of the output files? In this situation, consider using `std::filesystem::(recursive_)directory_iterator` instead to iterate the filesystem yourself. No temporary files needed. In any case, your `while` loop should probably be using `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`, and your `r_file` writes make no sense at all for what you are asking for.

Comment: I have to write the whole code in c ++ 11 max I can't use the filesystem from c ++ 17

Comment: then use `boost::filesystem`, or even OS-provided functions, to iterate the filesystem. The point is, using a shell command the way you are is not an efficient or preferred solution.